# Tab bar does not appear in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an iOS hybrid app, but I'm stuck on the first step;
my app does not show its tab bar like this pic [tab bar not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxPDt.jpg)

My debug result shows in `UITabBarController` the `self.tabBar.subviews.subviews` is empty when i try to traverse it, it throw an exception;[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2OSo.jpg)

here is the code;

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    BaseTabbarViewController *tabbarVC = [[BaseTabbarViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
//BaseTabbarViewController.m`
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self setupChildVC];
    self.indexFlag = 0;
}
- (void)setupChildVC {
    OKRWebViewController *okrMainVC = [[OKRWebViewController alloc] initWithConfig:@"http://192.168.2.183:8080/OKRMain?enable_bounds=0&hide_scroll_bar=1"];
    [self setupTabbarItem:okrMainVC.tabBarItem title:@"main" titleSize:12 titleFontName:@"HeiTi SC" normalTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] selectedTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] normalImage:@"tabbar_about_normal" selectedImage:@"tabar_select2"];
    OKRWebViewController *okrMainVC2 = [[OKRWebViewController alloc] initWithConfig:@"http://192.168.2.183:8080/OKRMain?enable_bounds=0&hide_scroll_bar=1"];
    [self setupTabbarItem:okrMainVC2.tabBarItem title:@"order" titleSize:12 titleFontName:@"HeiTi SC" normalTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] selectedTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] normalImage:@"tabbar_order_normal" selectedImage:@"tabar_select2"];
    BaseNavigationController *navA = [[BaseNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:okrMainVC];
    BaseNavigationController *navB = [[BaseNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:okrMainVC2];
    self.viewControllers = @[navA,navB];
}
- (void)upAnimationWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSMutableArray *tabBarButtonImageArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIControl *tabBarButton in self.tabBar.subviews) {
        if ([tabBarButton isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton")]) {
            for (UIView *imageView in tabBarButton.subviews) { // throw exception
                if ([imageView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarSwappableImageView")]) {
                    [tabBarButtonImageArray addObject:imageView];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

found some demos and I forked the code but that didn't work either, I'm not sure if different configurations would cause the issue;

`https://github.com/PrincessSmall/TabBarConteollerDemo#tabbarconteollerdemo`